# Who (if anyone) kidnapped Tommy?

Tags: movie, the-man-who-fell-to-earth

In the ending of *The Man Who Fell To Earth* his driver seemed to be kidnapping him (?). Was this related to the realization that he is an alien? Was he being kidnapped at the behest of the government or others in his company?

Answer (score 3):

Tommy was kidnapped by his driver at the behest of the government and taken to house arrest, where we find him in the following scene. It appears that his secret (e.g. that he's an alien) had been uncovered and he's subsequently medically examined.

In the film it's not clear how he was uncovered, but in the [source novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/245233/20774), the government were bugging him after he attracted a lot of attention to himself (e.g. turning up with an obviously fake past, making millions inventing new technologies) and overheard his conversation with Bryce.

> “That’s what I mean. Apparently you—Antheans, isn’t it?—aren’t
> altogether accustomed to thinking as we do. I believe any ordinary,
> human, detective magazine reader would have realized that we were
> bound to have had a microphone in your room in Chicago, when you were
> explaining yourself to Doctor Bryce.”